# Check if entered date in EXCEL VBA is date not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

Excel isDate returns true when I do not want it to be true.

For example

```
isDate(DateSerial(Month:=6, Day:=40, Year:=1970))
```

returns True

and inputing

```
DateSerial(Month:=6, Day:=40, Year:=1970))
```

as a value in a cell results in

10/7/1970

What I want is the user not to be able to enter 72nd of June but limit him to "real dates". I do not want Excel to compensate for it.

Is there a way?

Comment: How does the user input values for your date? Can you validate them before creating a date?

Comment: Date is calculated from social security number in Austria. For example 1111010170 is someone born on 1st of January 1970. There is no number like 1111400170. If the user enters it and I parse 40th day of January as a date I get 9th of February which is not what I want. I could limit certain parts of number to 31, 12 and so on, but there is still no 31st of February.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dateSerial-function is implemented on purpose like that - it can be handy if you want to add a number of days or months.

What you could do is to write your own checking routine that gets day, month and year as parameter, pass this as parameter to `DateSerial` and check if day, month and year are equal to the parameter values you passed.

```
Function checkValidDate(dd As Long, mm As Long, yyyy As Long) As Boolean
    Dim tmpDate As Date
    On Error Resume Next
    tmpDate = DateSerial(yyyy, mm, dd)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then Exit Function
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    checkValidDate = (Day(tmpDate) = dd And Month(tmpDate) = mm And Year(tmpDate) = yyyy)
End Function


? checkValidDate(0, 0, 0)
False

? checkValidDate(10, 7, 1970)
True

? checkValidDate(40, 6, 1970)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract and parse the text date and use `IsDate`:

```vb
PersonNummer = "1111010170"
If IsDate(Format(Right(PersonNummer, 6), "@@\/@@\/@@")) Then
    Debug.Print "OK"
Else
    Debug.Print "Not OK"
End If
```